# Beginner Android App Crashes

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a beginner android primer book and the code seems simple enough. However, it cannot run. When I try to run it, eclipse crashes.

Here's my java code:

```
package com.example.gamebeginner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;
    int touchCount;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Touch me!");
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        setContentView(button);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        touchCount++;
        button.setText("Touched me " + touchCount + " times(s)");
    }
}
```

---

activity.main xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gamebeginner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gamebeginner.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm on jdk version 1.6. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's logcat saying? You'll need to give us an excerpt from the log. :)

Comment: What error message do you get?  Will it simply not deploy to a device or will it run but then crash?

Comment: java se binary is not responding is the error message. It does not run at all. I try to run the program, and it freezes up. Then I get that binary message.

Comment: When posting problems like these it is very helpful to post the logcat output. It will include the error and other useful information. Here is some info on how to use logcat: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: On a separate note, if you are creating you activity's content view, you don't need the `activity.main.xml` layout file.

Comment: I cannot post logcat. When I try to click it, eclipse crashes.

Comment: Are you using a virtual device for emulation or are you using a real device to test on?

Comment: Go to `window -> show view -> android -> devices` click ok so that you open the device list. Now do you see your device listed in that window?

Comment: Ok, make sure that you click on the device so the device is highlighted. Now go and click on your logcat tab. If you do not have the logcat tab opened, go to `window -> show view -> other -> android -> logcat`. Make sure you DO NOT select the deprecated version. Does it still crash eclipse?

Comment: Actually I got the problem fixed. All I did was unplug my device and replug it. haha. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: How can I give you credit if you just commented? If I can't do that go ahead and post a reply so I can give you credit.

Comment: I added an answer. Have fun with android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Make sure you device is connected and working correctly.**

1. Go to window -> show view -> android -> devices click ok so that you
   open the device list. Make sure you see your device listed in the
   window.
2. Make sure that you click on the device so the device is highlighted.
   Now go and click on your logcat tab. If you do not have the logcat
   tab opened, go to window -> show view -> other -> android -> logcat.
   Make sure you DO NOT select the deprecated version.

Also try killing and restarting the adb daemon.

`adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` at a command prompt. If you do not have `adb` on your path, you will need to reference the full path to `adb` or do the command within the directory that contains `adb`.

**Disconnecting and reconnecting the device solved the issue.**

Answer (score 1):

If your error message (in logcat, right?) is `java se binary is not responding`, I would venture to say that you are generating the code in the wrong way somehow. Are you using Eclipse or IntelliJ to build your app? What is the project type you are using - Java application, or Android application?

Comment: The error message is not from logcat. It's a windows error message. Trying to retrieve logcat now.

Comment: And it's eclipse android app

Comment: Ugh, wait, what?! You are writing Android app, it's supposed to run on your phone (or in the emulator), and you shouldn't be seeing any error messages in Windows. I would venture to change my guess to 'you're building it as Android app, but trying to run it as a Java SE application locally on your development machine'.

Comment: I think in this instance it's because Eclipse (Running in the Java SE VM) crashed - his code would be riddled with syntax errors otherwise

Comment: Exactly what JRaymond said, eclipse is crashing. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

First add setContentView and afer View

Comment: Well, isn't he technically allowed to programmatically create a view to use as a "contentview"?